# filter dataframe from another dataframe column value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

we have two dataframes and we need to filter 
data in one dataframe with data in another dataframe column

```
df1
-------------------------------
name paid_amount date_paid
-------------------------------
aaa   10          2017-10-10
aba   10          2017-01-10
aac   10          2017-10-10
daa   10          2017-16-10

df2
-----------------------------
start_date end_date
-----------------------------
2017-01-01 2018-01-01
------------------------------

we need to create third dataframe by checking  
(date_paid) field in df1 falls in between df2(start_date) & df2(end_date)

df1.where($date_paid).isin(df2.start_date && df2.end_date)
```

Answer (score -1):

Should be:

```
df1.crossJoin(df2).where($"date_paid".between($"start_date", $"end_date"))
```